# What's the meaning of view.bounds.origin?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

say if I set view.bounds.origin to (50,50) ,then the subview is drawn (50,50) left up to view. But I thought it should be the inverse result, so what does bounds.origin mean?

sorry guys, I'm not a native English speaker,so I put this sample code and image this time~~

```
subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200)];
subview.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
subview.bounds = CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 200);

subsubview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,100,100)];
subsubview.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
[subview addSubView:subsubView];
```

this will cause this result:
[image]

so why the yellow view is located there?

Comment: What do you mean by "the inverse result"?

Comment: Can you clarify, possibly with some example code, which view you are setting the bounds.origin in and when you are adding the subview, and what the frame of the subview is?

Comment: where you have set the bounds.origin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html):

> On the screen, the bounds rectangle represents the same visible
>   portion of the view as its frame rectangle. By default, the origin of
>   the bounds rectangle is set to (0, 0) but you can change this value to
>   display different portions of the view.

What you've done by altering `bounds` is effectively to translate `subView`'s internal coordinate space down and to the right by 50 points. You've then added 'subsubView' with an origin of 0,0 within `subView`'s coordinate space - this is therefore 50 points up and to the left of the visible origin of `subView`.

If you had set `subView`'s `frame` instead of `bounds`, you would have moved `subView` within it's *superview's* coordinate space, so your blue square would have moved up and to the left, and the yellow square would be contained within it and have the same origin.

Setting `bounds` to something that doesn't have an origin of (0,0) is similar to adding a translation to the view. In nearly all circumstances, this isn't what you want to do, and you should be setting the `frame` property instead. Each view in a view hierarchy has its own coordinate space. `frame` is where a view is in relation to its superview, and `bounds` is the space within a view.

So, a subview's `frame` describes its location and size in the superview's `bounds`. If the superview's `bounds` has a non-zero origin, and you add a subview with a `frame` having a zero origin, it is going to be "outside" the superview's bounds.

Comment: "this is therefore 50 points up and to the left of the visible origin of subView" why is that, can you explain it a little bit more ?

Comment: 1. "f you had set subView's frame instead of bounds, you would have moved subView within it's superview's coordinate space, so your blue square would have moved up and to the left" I think you mistyped here, changing subView's frame (subView.frame.origin.x += 50, subView.frame.origin.y += 50) should move to the bottom right. Besides, I can't image what the bounds look like when its origin changes

Comment: That would move down and right, yes, but in the question the frame is going from an origin of 100,100 to an origin of 50,50.

Comment: I still don't understand. The subsubView frame origin is relative to the subView bounds origin, right ? But then subView.bounds.origin.x += 50, subView.bounds.origin.y += 50, you said that the subView internal coordinate system is translated to the bottom right, I can't imagine how that bounds look like

Comment: yes, they're relative. So if you start from 50,50, 0,0 is above and to the left of it. Subviews can be _outside the bounds_ of their superview.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is here. You agree that **The subsubView frame origin is relative to the subView bounds origin**. But then the subView bounds origin is translated to the bottom right, why does subsubView move to the top left ?

Comment: When you set the bounds origin of blue square to 50, 50, it moves the visible portion of it 50 right and 50 bottom. Then, when you add the yellow square with origin 0,0 the portions from x: 0 - 50, y: 0 - 50 is not visible within the blue square bounds.
Next, zoom out to the red background, you'll see their location. That's why the yellow is x:-50, y:-50 relative to the blue square "frame.origin"

Answer (score 4):

The problem is we usually think that when changing the `blue view` bounds origin (for example shift to the right bottom), then the yellow view should shifts right bottom too, as `yellow view` position is relative to its superview coordinate system (in this case the `blue view` bounds origin). This is not the case

Instead, we should think that the `blue view` defines a mask in which it only shows a portion of the the rectangle in its coordinate space. So if we change the `blue view` bounds origin to the right bottom, it just shifts the mask to the right bottom, and only the views inside that mask is shown. And to the `red view`, it always shows that mask at a fixed position (`blue view` frame origin does not change). Think of the `red view` taking the `blue view` mask and putting at the position defined by the `blue view` frame

Just found this [Understanding UIScrollView](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/04/understanding-uiscrollview/) by Ole which is very helpful and explains it very clearly

I strongly recommend reading this

> A view provides a **viewport** into the plane defined by its coordinate
>   system. The viewʼs bounds rectangle describe the position and size of
>   the visible area.
>
> It looks as though the view has moved down by 100 points, and this is
>   in fact true in relation to its own coordinate system. The viewʼs
>   actual position on the screen (or in its superview, to put it more
>   accurately) remains fixed, however, as that is determined by its
>   frame, which has not changed

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I found my aha moment reading this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your blue view's frame is still 100, 100, 200, 200.  The bounds are 50, 50, 200, 200, but the frame is unchanged.

The yellow view is added to the blue view, at 0, 0, within the bounds, not the frame.  So the yellow is showing up at 50, 50, 50, 50.

Change:

`subview.bounds = CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 200);`

To:

`subview.bounds = CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200);`

and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

> On the screen, the bounds rectangle represents the same visible
>   portion of the view as its frame rectangle. By default, the origin of
>   the bounds rectangle is set to (0, 0) but you can change this value to
>   display different portions of the view. The size of the bounds
>   rectangle is coupled to the size of the frame rectangle, so that
>   changes to one affect the other. Changing the bounds size grows or
>   shrinks the view relative to its center point. The coordinates of the
>   bounds rectangle are always specified in points.

From [UIView's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/bounds).

Studying [View Programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html) is also going to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

UIWindow: frame == bounds  ::==> (0 , 0 , windowWidth, windowHeight)

subview: frame ::==> (100, 100, 200, 200) on UIWindows bounds [UIWindows cordinate space.]

When you do this:

```
subview.bounds = CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 200);
```

You are saying that subview's subview frame will start with (50,50, 200, 200) if that subview's subview [subsubview] were to cover the subview properly.

Just as you would need to specify your subview's frame to (0,0, windowWidth, windowHeight) to cover the window properly with your subview.

The point is, A SUBVIEWS frame is dependent on its immediate SUPERVIEWS cordinate system. The local/internal cordinate system of the immediate superview is its bounds.

Coming to the point why is the subsubview up and left by 50 50 points.

```
subview.bounds = CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 200);

subsubview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,100,100)];
```

compare between (0,0) and (50,50).
We said subview's local/internal cordinate space to be of (50,50, 200, 200)
We then added subview's subview [subsubview] at (0,0) inside a view **subview** which starts at (50,50).

In this case, (0,0) is top left of (50,50). That is why this happened.

If you dont get what it means even now, then take a deep look and draw some rectangles in the notebook slowly. Its tricky to get it right first hand.